Guacamole Docker version - must login to mySQL to work
I have a nice installation of Guacamole on Oracle Linux 8, on OCI. Repostiory can be found at https://github.com/timyshark/guacamole.
in summary: docker-compose.yaml:
# import .env file from volt
# Generate ./initdb.sql : $ mkdir initdb && docker run --rm guacamole/guacamole /opt/guacamole/bin/initdb.sh --mysql > ./initdb/initdb.sql

# networks
# create a network 'guacamole_net' in mode 'bridged'
networks:
  guac-net:
driver: bridge
  haproxy_net:
external: true

# services
services:
  # guacd
  guacd:
container_name: guac-guacd
image: guacamole/guacd
networks:
  guac-net:
restart: always

  # mysql
  mysql:
container_name: guac-mysql
environment:
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}'
  MYSQL_DATABASE: '${MYSQL_DATABASE}'
  MYSQL_USER: '${MYSQL_USER}'
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${MYSQL_PASSWORD}'
image: mysql:oraclelinux8
networks:
  guac-net:
restart: always
volumes:
- ./initdb:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

  # guacamole
  guacamole:
container_name: guac-guacamole
depends_on:
- guacd
- mysql
environment:
  GUACD_HOSTNAME: guacd
  MYSQL_HOSTNAME: mysql
  MYSQL_DATABASE: '${MYSQL_DATABASE}'
  MYSQL_USER: '${MYSQL_NAME}'
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${MYSQL_PASSWORD}'
  MYSQL_SSL_MODE: disabled
image: guacamole/guacamole
ports:
- "8080:8080"
links:
- guacd
networks:
  - guac-net
restart: always

All working good, except on first docker compose up I got the error
 An error has occurred and this action cannot be completed. If the problem persists, please notify your system administrator or check your system logs.

And the log:
guac-guacamole  | Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
guac-guacamole  | 21:17:00.399 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] WARN  o.a.g.e.AuthenticationProviderFacade - The "mysql" authentication provider has encountered an internal error which will halt the authentication process. If this is unexpected or you are the developer of this authentication provider, you may wish to enable debug-level logging. If this is expected and you wish to ignore such failures in the future, please set "skip-if-unavailable: mysql" within your guacamole.properties.
guac-guacamole  | 21:17:00.404 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] ERROR o.a.g.rest.RESTExceptionMapper - Unexpected internal error:
guac-guacamole  | ### Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Public Key Retrieval is not allowed
guac-guacamole  | ### The error may exist in org/apache/guacamole/auth/jdbc/user/UserMapper.xml
guac-guacamole  | ### The error may involve org.apache.guacamole.auth.jdbc.user.UserMapper.selectOne
guac-guacamole  | ### The error occurred while executing a query
guac-guacamole  | ### Cause: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Public Key Retrieval is not allowed

I am not sure how to solve the problem , or change the driver as noted in the log.
if I log in to mysql container using user guacamole/password just once I get in to http://guacamole-server:8080/guacamole
$docker exec -it guac-mysql bash
#mysql -u guacamole guacamoledb -p


I noticed that in the mysql service you're using MYSQL_USER but in guacamole you're using MYSQL_NAME. Is that intentional?

nop wasn't intentional, but working at 3AM makes my eyes twiggle, thanks for the correction, in the code it was MYSQL_USER, but slipped due to copy and paste

This setup works reliably for me:
version: "3.7"

services:
  guacd:
    image: guacamole/guacd
    restart: always

  mysql:
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "-uroot", "-p${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}", "ping"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./initdb:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

  guacamole:
    depends_on:
      guacd:
        condition: service_started
      mysql:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      GUACD_HOSTNAME: guacd
      MYSQL_HOSTNAME: ${MYSQL_HOSTNAME}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DRIVER: mysql
      MYSQL_SSL_MODE: disabled
    image: guacamole/guacamole
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    links:
      - guacd
    restart: always

Things that I changed:

Use earlier MySQL image (mysql:5.7.22).
Specify an explicit health check for the mysql service, which ensures that MySQL is ready for connections before Guacamole even starts.

I'm using the default network but you can integrate your specific network.

Works great, much appreciated, yes that solves the problem

only twist I made is this:      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "-u${MYSQL_USER}", "-p${MYSQL_PASSWORD}", "ping"] and it works , didn't work for root login :/
